# Convert PDF to PNG using ImageMagick

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, imagemagick

using ImageMagick, what command should i use to convert a PDF to PNG? I need highest quality, smallest file size. this is what I have so far (very slow by the way):

```
convert -density 300 -depth 8 -quality 85 a.pdf a.png
```

Looking at what Gmail does when a user "view" a PDF, the quality is awesome and the file size very minimal. The DPI is just 96 (I have to set a density of 300 to get anything decent). Anyone know how GMail does it? Thanks.

Comment: Using `density` is also the solution of the converted image too **blur**.

Comment: `I need highest quality, smallest file size.` At the same time? Impossible. Welcome to the real world!

Comment: I guess he meant *maximum quality with minimum file size possible* or as sharp as original quality without adding unnecessary artifacts that increase file size without making image better. In that case, try `convert -density 192 input.pdf -quality 100 -alpha remove output.png` somehow `-quality 100` may lower the file size. 192 double 96dpi is good enough, and `-alpha remove` to remove transparent png background.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

when you set the density to 96, doesn't it look good?

when i tried it i saw that saving as jpg resulted with better quality, but larger file size

Comment: just tried 
convert -density 96 -quality 85 a.pdf a.png
and the results are very good

Comment: What is the full command line for this? When I try to run this on a Windows machine it's running the Windows "convert" command.

Comment: on Windows preface the "convert" command with "magick" to get it to work.

magick convert -density 300 -depth 8 -quality 85 a.pdf a.png

Comment: Disagree, density 96 is not good enough for pdf text doucment. And jpg may result worse result for pdf text document; jpg make larger file size with artifacts and worse quality for text. **png** however, result better in smaller file size and text quality; Use `-alpha remove` to remove png transparent background.

Answer (score 94):

[Reducing the image size](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?p=54853&sid=1525b3ad11155f1b4ff1ad4d0a76ca5e#p54853) before output results in something that looks sharper, in my case:

```
convert -density 300 a.pdf -resize 25% a.png
```

Comment: This methods worked for me while the accepted answer did not. In particular, the resulting thin lines are now OK while they were hugely aliased before.

Comment: Doesn't work for me it claims it doesn't find the file.

Comment: Downloaded the [ImageMagick-7.0.6-0-portable-Q16-x64.zip](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

Comment: And ran the command in the commandline. 
#shiftenteringishard

Comment: On Windows you need to run `magick convert -density ...` because "convert" is a Windows system utility.

Comment: @Andreas Or you can just use full path, eg. `C:\MyFiles\convert -density ...`

Comment: One has to be careful with transparency. I would suggest to follow https://stackoverflow.com/a/47174466/376454, especially `-alpha off`.

Answer (score 3):

To get high quality, one should do "supersampling" in Imagemagick. Convert at a high density, but then resize down as needed (nominal enough to compensate for the high density).

```
convert -density 288 input.pdf -resize 25% output.png
```

```
288=72*4 (72 dpi is default density, so 4x)
25%=1/4
```

So the 1/4 compensates for the 4x.

Comment: 72 dpi is default for PDF not necessarily screen. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36905337/default-imagemagick-density-when-converting-from-pdf. Feel free to use any density and fraction you want.

Comment: This works great, nevertheless I am not using the `-resize 25%` as it makes the text blurry and some images suffer some kind of compression, pixelated.

Comment: I can confirm, my text becomes a lot fuzzier than it will be with -density 192 without -resize.

Comment: Then do not resize and just find the density that makes the image sharp enough for you and has an acceptable size.

Answer (score 1):

```
convert -density 192 input.pdf -quality 100 -alpha remove output.png
```

for pdf text document is good enough.
`-density 192` double 96dpi, higher just make bigger image and file size
`-quality 100` somehow this give slightly smaller file size
`-alpha remove` to remove png transparent background