# default imagemagick density when converting from pdf

Tags: imagemagick

we have the following code

`convert foo.pdf foo.tiff`

this has been working fine for years, and the resulting tiff is a reasonable print quality.

we just upgraded imagemagick and now the tiffs are low resolution.

I am assuming that something changed in a recent IM upgrade, and I will have to explicitly specify the density:

`convert -density 300 foo.pdf foo.tiff`

Is this a correct assumption? Does anybody know if this has changed recently?

I just want to make sure there is nothing else wrong...

Comment: The [ChangeLog](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/changelog.php) is a good place to look.

Comment: first place I looked :-)

Answer (score 2):

> The default resolution is **72** dots per inch

Source: [Imagemagick command line options](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php), **-density** section