# ImageMagick convert pdf with multiple pages to high quality PNG

Tags: pdf, imagemagick

I am trying to convert a multi-page PDF to one long png with the following command:

`convert -append -flatten -density 300 in.pdf out.png`

I am using `-flatten` to lose transparency, since I want a white background in the final PNG. The problem is that it takes only the first page instead of using all the pages.

How can I convert the PDF to one long PNG while losing the transparency and using a white background?

Comment: Try adding `-adjoin`

Comment: nope.. doesn't work :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This command works for me on IM 6.9.9.22 Q16 Mac OSX with Ghostscript 9.21

```
convert -density 300 -colorspace sRGB itc101_13.pdf -alpha off -append out.png
```

[image]

If it does not work for you, then what is your ImageMagick version and what is your Ghostscript version.

Comment: Well, its working great but sometimes it outputs the PNG with a black background.. :-/

Comment: Here is my final command, seems to be working:
`convert -density 300 -background white -colorspace sRGB -alpha remove in.pdf -append out.png`

Answer (score 0):

You have your syntax wrong. You must read the PDF before applying append. Try

convert -density 300 -colorspace sRGB in.pdf +adjoin -append -background white -flatten out.png

If that does not work, then what is your ImageMagick version and platform? What is your Ghostscript version and your libpng version? Can post a link to your PDF file?

Note that +adjoin is not usually necessary for output to PNG, but won't hurt.

Comment: Still not working, thats my PDF:
https://taxes.gov.il/TaxesFormsList/itc101_13.pdf

I need a high quality PNG (300dpi), lose PDF transparency and support multiple pages from the PDF by making it a long PNG.