# Load PDF Image into MATLAB

Tags: matlab, pdf

I have a PDF of building schematics. I would like to load it into MATLAB, and visualize the image via a GUI, so I can measure distances and such for some calculations.

I have no idea if this is even possible?

Furthermore, the PDF has an embedded scale (i.e. 1 cm = 1 meter). If I can extract this as well, that would be awesome.

I found `extractFileText` which can be used to extract text, but not much else.

Answer (score 1):

I found the easiest way to do this was to convert the pdf to a image, for example using `imagemagick`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2869908/4196396)

If you add an example of the image someone might be able to suggest some ideas for extracting the scale information using image processing.